# Can resources in Alexandria's side A second wonder be bought by other players?

Tags: 7-wonders

On the Alexandria board side A, are players allowed to buy the resources given in the second wonder? Or are they 'special resources' like the ones give by yellow cards... aka not transferable to other players.

edit:
Sorry the rules state that "Clarification: these resources cannot be bought by neighboring cities."

Comment: Why don’t you remove the edit from the question and answer your own question instead? :)

Comment: wow, I'm surprised by the answer.

Comment: @ikegami It makes sense that others can't buy it because otherwise would be a possible detriment to you winning by building the wonder. Players that trade with Alexandria would be almost guaranteed a resource that they wouldn't have to waste building themselves.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is easily answered by rules reference or Google search.

Comment: @Tynam Many rules questions can be answered by finding the right place in the rules, but that doesn't mean that they should be closed.  "General Reference" is a close reason that is used very rarely, as it should be.

Comment: While I agree with you, @bwarner, this one felt like the rare exception to me: the rule is in the first place you'd look, and it's a short sentence that needs no further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

As the asker points out, the rules specifically clarify that the resources are like those provided by yellow cards and cannot be bought by neighboring cities.